# how can i listen click event on <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i want to listen click on audio ,but the below code, it doesn't work

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" >
  <source src="horse.mp3" >
您的浏览器不支持 audio 元素。
</audio>
    
<script>
    console.log(1);
    const audioElement =  document.querySelector('audio')

    audioElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('============ addEventListener =============');
    });
</script>
```

i use addEventListener

Comment: This code works fine for me, tested on multiple browsers. Please describe in more detail what you want to accomplish. What device/browsers are you having an issue on?

Comment: i want to add a click listener on  audio, it should log '============ addEventListener =============', when i click audio